# Sequelize order by issue

Tags: sequelize.js

Update - happens only when using [sequelize-virtual-fields](https://github.com/overlookmotel/sequelize-virtual-fields) module

I'm trying to define a simple default scope order by column, with no success.

this is my case:

got a simple entity configured:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var DeviceType = sequelize.define('DeviceType', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'DeviceID',
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    field: 'DeviceType'
  }
},
{
  tableName: 'm_DeviceType',
  timestamps: false,
  defaultScope:{
    order: [['name']]
  }
 }
);
 return DeviceType;
};
```

when I try to fetch a list I get:

> {"message":"internal error","errors":["ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'DeviceType.name' in 'order clause'"]}

if I try to change order field to the column name I get

> {"message":"internal error","errors":["Field 'DeviceType.DeviceType' referenced in a virtual field does not exist"]}

Am I doing something wrong?

I use the latest seqeulize version

Comment: What is your backing DB? In my tests with pg, defaultScope:{ order: [['DeviceType']]   } works.

Comment: What version of sequelize you use ?

Comment: I used version 3.14.0

Comment: I think I found the bug, see update